# Why pygame.draw.circle doesn't work in this code?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a ball object that waits one second in the middle of the screen before moving. This is the `update` method:

```
def update(self, dt):
    now = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000
    if now - self._spawn_time >= BALL_WAIT_TIME: 
        self.rect = self.calcnewpos(dt)
        self.handle_collision()
    else:
        step = 255 / FPS
        value = int(self._frame * step)
        rgb = (value, value, value)
        self._draw_ball(rgb)
        self._frame += 1
```

That one second happens below the **else** clause. My goal is to have the ball image go from **black** `(8, 8, 8)` to **white** `(255, 255, 255)` in that time but as it is `_draw_ball` doesn't do anything.

```
def _draw_ball(self, rgb):
    pygame.draw.circle(self.image, rgb, self.rect.center, BALL_RADIUS)
```

The funny things is, it works the first time when it's called in `__init__`. I've tried taking lines out of update and testing this code on its own in another module but can't figure out what's the problem. Why is `pygame.draw.circle` not drawing the the circles in the colors passed by the update method?

Here is the whole class:

```
#!python3
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game, velocity):
        super(Ball, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((BALL_RADIUS*2, BALL_RADIUS*2))
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK, RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area = screen.get_rect().inflate(-GAP*2, 0)

        self.velocity = velocity
        self.game = game
        self.start_to_the = random.choice(['left', 'right'])
        self._draw_ball(BALL_COLOR)
        self.reinit()

    def _draw_ball(self, rgb):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, rgb, self.rect.center, BALL_RADIUS)

    def _hit_topbottom(self):
        return self.rect.top < self.area.top or self.rect.bottom > self.area.bottom

    def _hit_leftright(self):
        if self.rect.left < self.area.left: return 'left'
        elif self.rect.right > self.area.right: return 'right'
        else: return 0

    def reinit(self):
        self._spawn_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000
        self._frame = 1

        if self.start_to_the == 'left':
            self.velocity = Vec2D(-BALL_SPEED, 0)
        else:
            self.velocity = Vec2D(BALL_SPEED, 0)

        self.rect.center = self.area.center

    def update(self, dt):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 1000
        if now - self._spawn_time >= BALL_WAIT_TIME: 
            self.rect = self.calcnewpos(dt)
            self.handle_collision()
        else:
            step = 255 / FPS
            value = int(self._frame * step)
            rgb = (value, value, value)
            self.image.fill(rgb)
            self._frame += 1

    def calcnewpos(self, dt):
        (dx, dy) = self.velocity.x, self.velocity.y
        return self.rect.move(dx, dy)

    def handle_collision(self):
        (dx, dy) = self.velocity.x, self.velocity.y
        if self._hit_topbottom():
            dy = -dy

        elif self._hit_leftright():
            side = self._hit_leftright()

            self.game.enemy.update_hitpos()
            self.game.increase_score(side)

            if side == 'left': self.start_to_the = 'right'
            elif side == 'right': self.start_to_the = 'left'
            self.reinit()
            return

        else:
            if self.hit_paddle():
                paddle = self.hit_paddle()
                paddle.handle_collision()

                if paddle == self.game.paddles['left']:
                    self.rect.left = GAP + PADDLE_WIDTH
                elif paddle == self.game.paddles['right']: 
                    self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH - (GAP + PADDLE_WIDTH)
                dx = -dx

                dy = (self.rect.centery - paddle.rect.centery)
                dy = (math.copysign(min(abs(dy) // 16 * 16, 32), dy)) / 4

                paddle.handle_collision()
        self.velocity = Vec2D(dx, dy)

    def hit_paddle(self):
        paddles = self.game.paddles.values()
        for paddle in paddles:
            if self.rect.colliderect(paddle.rect): return paddle
```

Comment: Paste more of the class definition. Trying putting a few print lines in your update method to see where it's getting drawn, and what colour.

Comment: @Aesthete I did. The rgb values are passed correctly and in valid range `(0, 255)`. The position of the circle is right... Like I said, it works the first time it is called in `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any calls to `pygame.display.flip`.  This is the function responsible for updating the screen with the current state of your display surface.  It also doesn't look like you are redrawing your ball on the display surface.  Somewhere, probably in `update` or `_draw_ball` there should be calls like the following:

```
self.screen.draw(self.image, self.rect)
pygame.display.flip()
```

The first line draws the image of the ball to the surface representing the screen, and the second call updates the screen to reflect the new surface.

My second theory is that you are drawing new frames of the ball outside of the bounds of `self.image`.  This theory comes from seeing that are moving the ball's rect according to velocity, but always drawing a circle on `self.image` at `self.rect`'s center.  The size of `self.image` is only `BALL_RADIUS*2`, which makes it easy to draw outside of it if `self.rect`'s topleft becomes something that's not `(0,0)`.  Even if this isn't your problem now, it will be later.

Comment: But `_draw_ball` only changes the ball image. It's not supposed to draw anything to the screen, only to the `image` surface. In the game's main loop the ball is drawn based on its image.

Comment: Also, if you replace `self._draw_ball(rgb)` with `self.image.fill(rgb)` it works perfectly.

Comment: Your `if` block before the `else` block that updates the ball color looks suspicious.  Are you sure you're not moving the ball's rect to some place where it won't update a relevant portion of `self.image`?  Try commenting out that code.

Comment: The `if` block doesn't update the color, only calculates the position of the `rect` and handles collision. This is what happens: **1.** someone scores (the ball goes out of the screen). **2.** ball's `reinit` is called which, besides some unrelevant stuff, sets the ball position to the center of the screen. **3.** then in the main loop, ball's `update` is called. So `self.rect.center` there is right :(

Comment: Right, but you've defined the dimensions of `self.image` as `BALL_RADIUS*2`, and you're drawing the circle at the position of `self.rect`.  If the rect has moved at all, then you will draw the circle outside the bounds of `self.image`.  Add a few prints, and determine without doubt that the rect is not moving.

Comment: Just checked it again. The rect's top left corner stays at `(310, 230)` while `if now - self._spawn_time >= BALL_WAIT_TIME` is `False`. Also, if the rect did change, replacing `self._draw_ball(rgb)` with `self.image.fill(rgb)` would show it.

Answer (score 0):

in pygame the draw circle statement is  :
    pygame.draw.circle (SURFACE, COLOUR, (X, Y), SIZE, 0)
if you put your screen.fill statement after the circle statement then it will draw the circle and immediately cover it up with the colour of the screen, making your circle disappear a 10000th of a second after its drawn.